# ClojureScript - get checkbox element value

Tags: clojurescript

I have the following code (from `om.next`) creating a checkbox input. The creation works fine, but I don't know how to get the event value, as I don't see the value somewhere in the logs when I click on it (there is a lot of data though) :

```
(dom/input #js {:type    "checkbox"
                :onClick (fn [e] (js/console.log e)) ;; how do I get the current true/false value from `e` ?
               })
```

I get in the logs (abbreviated) :

> SyntheticMouseEvent {dispatchConfig: Object, dispatchMarker:
>   ".0.0.1.$[cardpath]=1[om_tutorial=1B_UI_Exercises]=1[exercise-3].0.$-184795562.1.0",
>   nativeEvent: MouseEvent, target: input, currentTarget: input…}

Note : the code is from [there](https://github.com/awkay/om-tutorial/blob/master/src/tutorial/om_tutorial/B_UI_Exercises.cljs#L82).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(.- target e)` returns you the element,
generally you want the `.-value` from an element, but for a checkbox you want `.-checked` instead... so something like

```
(.. e -target -checked)
```

Comment: Right I missed that ! I did not know the `..` function also. Does it survive `:advanced` compilation ? I will accept as soon as I can.

Comment: yes it works with :advanced, .. is just shorthand, it expands to identical code. http://clojure.org/reference/java_interop has a brief description